# Reduce long white spaces to a single character

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm using ruby and I'm trying to reduce a long white spaces to a single character. This is the code I'm trying:

```
str = hello world    how     are  you 
puts str.gsub(/\s/, '#')
```

Output of my current code:

```
hello#world####how#####are##you
```

Desired output:

```
hello#world#how#are#you
```

Any idea how to reach my desired output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
puts str.gsub(/\s+/, '#')
```

Answer (score 3):

You are close, you missing the matching of the regex for more than one spaces. Try this:

```
str.gsub(/\s+/, '#')
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

```
str = hello world    how     are  you

puts str.gsub(/\s+/, '#')

# => hello#world#how#are#you
```

Answer (score 2):

```
"hello world    how     are  you"
.squeeze(" ").tr(" ", "#")
# => "hello#world#how#are#you"
```

Answer (score 0):

[As the user Iain asked for explanation of what I did]

In Regex, \s+ means 1 or more whitespace character. Using, ruby's [gsub](http://apidock.com/ruby/String/gsub) method, I am replacing the matching pattern ( in this case, 1 or more whitespace characters) with the '#' character. And, I am testing this example code in [irb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_Ruby_Shell).

```
    1.9.3-p327 :013 > str = "hello world    how     are  you" 
     => "hello world    how     are  you"  
    1.9.3-p327 :016 > str.gsub(/\s+/, '#')
     => "hello#world#how#are#you"
```

extra tip: [rubular](http://rubular.com/) is a great online tool to test and play with Regexp!

Comment: Please can you leave an explanation of what you doing?